# Hybird graphics - drivers installation

Tags: drivers, ati

*Quick translation:*

Good morning

My name is Jorge Andres Barrios and am new to the Linux OS. I have had many problems with installing drivers on my PC; my computer is an HP Pavilion DM4 with hybrid graphics. These are the details of my graphics card:

```
00: 02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

01: 00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD / ATI] Robson CE [Radeon HD 6370M / 7370M]
```

I want to install the propirietary ATI driver, as I have read that they are very good, but whenever I install them, my computer is only able to start in DOS mode.

I hope I can contribute to the topic, since I am new to Linux and I would like to learn more.

---

*Original text:*

buenos dias;

mi nombre es jorge andres barrios y soy nuevo con el S.O Linux, he tenido muchos inconvenientes con el tema de la instalacion de drivers en mi PC; mi computador es un HP Pavilion dm4 con una tarjeta grafica hibrida. estos son los datos de mi tarjeta grafica:

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Robson CE [Radeon HD 6370M/7370M]

quiero instalar los driver ATI, ya que he leido que son muy buenos;

pero siempre que realizo una instalacion se me daña el video y el equipo unicia en modo DOS

espero que me puedan colanborar con el tema, ya que soy nuevo en linux y quiero aprender mucho de el